# How to reliably map physical ethernet port location to eth0/1

Tags: debian, systemd, systemd-networkd

I'm using Debian 9 (stretch). I have a motherboard with four ethernet interfaces stacked two on top, two on bottom. For my use-case, I'm only using two of them. Here's my question: how do I make the top left one eth0, and the top right one eth1?

Initially that probably sounds easy. "Use the MAC address" is probably your first response. Sadly, it's not that easy. I need this to scale to hundreds of these motherboards, some of which will end up on the same network, so the MACs will be unique.

Here is a snippet of `lspci` output:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

My initial take at this was to figure out which of these corresponds to the physical interfaces I care about, and use systemd network link files that look something like this:

```
[Match]
Path=pci-0000:02:00.0
[Link]
NamePolicy=
Name=eth0
```

That actually seems to work MOSTLY fine. The problem is that the BDF isn't actually stable. Sometimes I need to put a firewire card in here that ends up claiming a earlier bus number and it bumps all the ethernet interfaces back:

```
02:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments XIO2213A /B/XIO2221 IEEE-1394b OHCI Controller [Cheetah Express] (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

The grouping of four never seems to be split, though. Can someone confirm that at least the relative order of these four devices is well-defined between multiple identical motherboards? Perhaps more specifically: can I rely on the idea that a particular `IFINDEX` reliably points to the same physical port across multiple identical motherboards? That seems to be my experience so far, but I haven't found anything actually confirming it beyond anecdotally. Even if that were true, then I run into the fact that the systemd version in stretch doesn't support the `Property` key in link files. I appear to be stuck with only `MACAddress`, `Path`, `Driver`, `Type`, `Name`, `Host`, `Virtualization`, `KernelCommandLine`, or `Architecture`.

For now, the best solution I've found is to use the [deprecated udev support](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames) and throw something like this into `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086", ATTRS{device}=="0x1533", ATTR{ifindex}=="5", NAME:="eth0"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086", ATTRS{device}=="0x1533", ATTR{ifindex}=="3", NAME:="eth1"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086", ATTRS{device}=="0x1533", ATTR{ifindex}=="4", NAME:="eth2"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086", ATTRS{device}=="0x1533", ATTR{ifindex}=="2", NAME:="eth3"
```

Is there any way for me to do this in the New World before systemd v243? Is there something better/more stable than IFINDEX?

Comment: "Can someone confirm that at least the order of these devices is well-defined between multiple identical motherboards?" The order is not necessarily consistent: I have a number of identical Lenovo blade servers (same hardware, same BIOS), for example, and they're split about 50/50 between slot 5 and slot 6 for the embedded NIC.

Comment: @larsks interesting, so you'd say that `IFINDEX` would not be useful, then? Is this a problem you've had to solve? I clarified in the question a little: I'm curious about the relative ordering of multiple NICs rather than the overall lspci ordering. Also, are you sure those are actually the same motherboard? It seems like they wouldn't NEED to be in order to call the server the same thing.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was commenting about PCI slot ordering, not the relative ordering of interfaces.

Comment: Yeah the instability of that ordering is pretty well established at this point. I'm willing to bet that the real answer to my question is "no, nothing guarantees that, but also it's pretty common for that to be the case because of how the enumeration happens and how these devices are physically grouped."